# 503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, amazon-ec2, unicorn

I have Amazone-E2 Server. My Rails application working on nginx and Unicorn. Suddenly I'm getting

```
503 (Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity)
```

Unable to understand How to fix this issue. 
Kindly Help Please....

Comment: any more information? or if you ask about himself fix it

Comment: Read log rails(log/production.log) and probably Nginx (access and error) and Unicorn. Also Amazon must have web-utilites for show server-status, like a CPU, RAM, traffic

Answer (score 0):

You most likely misconfigured your health-check (or your health-check returns an error because your (proxy-) server is not working correctly). Check your ELB logs.